# How to delete Line in the datagrid?

Tags: livecode

I need to remove first three lines from the datagrid group "DFP" and remaining lines comes in the place of 1st 2nd and third respectively.

```
put the dgHilitedLines of group "DFP"  into theLine
   DeleteLine theLine
```

I used the above code, but its shows the following error

button "Pass": execution error at line 22 (Handler: can't find handler) near "DeleteLine", char 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a row in datagrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436489/how-to-delete-a-row-in-datagrid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daatgrids have more properties than normal controls, see: http://livecode.wikia.com/wiki/Datagrid_API

I suggest you to use the **dgText** property, like the following code:

```
put the dgText of group "DFP" into temp
delete line 1 to 2 of temp
set the dgText of group "DFP" to temp
```